# Authenticating Jupyter Notebook inside Docker keeps resulting in invalid token

Tags: authentication, docker, token, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook from inside a docker container. I am running

```
jupyter  notebook --allow-root --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0
```

which produces

`[I 20:04:41.067 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /local/directory/path/
[I 20:04:41.067 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 20:04:41.067 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=8950efa69b640e2b330dd86007b295f96d33d93cdd584830
[I 20:04:41.068 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 20:04:41.179 NotebookApp]`

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=8950efa69b640e2b330dd86007b295f96d33d93cdd584830`
```

When I go to log into the browser, however, at the link, I am prompted to enter a token and the one above (`895...`) returns "invalid token."

I'm running Jupyter 4.3.0.

How do I open the notebook?

Yes, there is a similar question to this but the token outputted above works in their case.

Comment: It appears the solution to this is coming in version 5.1 according to this thread: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2375

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I can't find the solution in the github thread

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not forward the port from the container to the host when running the container:
`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tag --port=8888`
But that should give you a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` unless you already have a jupyter running locally on 8888, which of course does not recognize the token from docker instance. Try to run the container with port forwarding and make sure it's a different port than any local instances.